# What does it mean when there are 2 volumes are attached to 1 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

In the Amazon EC2 dashboard, I have one instance running.

When I look up volumes in EBS, it shows 2 volumes "State: In use" both attached to same instance.

One volume is /dev/xvda (attached)
and the other one is i-20aaa52c (aflexsystem):/dev/sdf (attached)

How does that work? and can I deattach one of them while not losing any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of EBS volumes as hard disks. You can have more than one hard disk attached to your server, right? Same with EBS volumes, except EBS vols are *much* more flexible. You can clone them, snapshot them, move them easily between servers, etc.

Whether or not you can detach them depends on what you're using them for. For that, you'll need to do some investigation of your own. Look at the output of `mount` to see where these devices are being used. If they're being used in critical filesystem locations, you will need to shut down the server and then detach it.